# Ошибка при переключении пунктов меню

Tags: android, android-layout, menu, toolbar, yandexmapkit

Доброго времени суток.

Подключил в проект yandexmapkit.
После работы со layout карты (при переходе в другой пункт меню) возникает ошибка. См. скрины. Поиск в гугле и по stackoverflow не помог.

[image: Ошибка при выборе пункта меню "Категория товара"]

Т.е. при переключении отображается только три первых буквы пункта меню и все...

Если нажать на кнопку поиска, то меню обновляется, слой перерисовывается и дальше все работает нормально до обращения к карте.

[![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]

Сложность в том, что ошибка воспроизводится не регулярно, т.е. первый переход приводит к ошибке, второй может не привести...

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать???

Comment: Скриншоты не несут никакой полезной информации. Уберите их и покажите код.

Comment: обрезанный заголовок из за того, что в ActionBar не хватает места для полного заголовка (например виджет поиска занимает много места). Это не ошибка, а неправильная компоновка.

Comment: Похоже что Вы правы, если развернуть устройство, ошибка не воспроизводится!

Comment: Буду читать мануалы по верстке. Спасибо.

Comment: Владимир, знать бы что показывать :). Проект из ряда модулей... В принципе направление решения подсказали... Спасибо.

Comment: Включите Настройки > Для разработчиков > Показывать границы элементов